# Comparar keys de 2 objetos

Tags: javascript

alguien me podría ayudar con este ejercicio?         sé que con el metodo Object.keys() recibo los nombres de las keys, pero como hago para corroborar si cada una de ellas está en el otro objeto? es en JavaScript

```
 function clavesUnicas(obj1, obj2) {
    // La funcion recibe dos objetos "obj1" y "obj2".
    // Retornar las keys de las propiedades que sean únicas en cada objeto.
    // Ej:
    // let obj1 = {nombre: "Luciano", apellido: "Nicolau"}
    // let obj2 = {nombre: "Lio", segundoNombre: "Gustavo"}
    // clavesUnicas(obj1, obj2) retorna => ["apellido", "segundoNombre"];
    //
    // Tu código`:
};
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado por tu cuenta? Las preguntas que no muestran un esfuerzo mínimo terminan cerradas. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Si te hacen los deberes nunca aprenderás a programar. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Se puede realizar de la siguiente manera en tiempo lineal:

Recorres todas llaves del objeto `obj1` y agregas a un arreglo aquellas que no estén en `obj2`

Y luego haces lo mismo pero agregas todas las de `obj2` que no estén en `obj1`.

```js
const clavesUnicas = (obj1, obj2) => {
  // un check para saber si obj1 no es null, undefined... sería bueno
  
  // obtenemos llaves unicas en obj1
  const uniqueProps = Object.keys(obj1).filter(key1 => !(key1 in obj2))

  // obtenemos llaves unicas en obj2
  return uniqueProps.concat(Object.keys(obj2).filter(key2 => !(key2 in obj1)))
};

const res = clavesUnicas({
  a: "bds",
  b: "",
  c: ""
}, {
  a: "",
  d: "",
  e: "",
  c: ""
});

console.log(res);
```

La anterior función puede tener muchos cambios, por ejemplo en lugar de obtener las llaves con `Object.keys` las podrías obtener con `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, en lugar del `.concat` podrías usar *array-destructuring*, puedes reemplazar `in` por un acceso con `[]`, ... todo depende de qué es lo que quieras hacer.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero si detallas bien la pregunta, el OP no ha mostrado ningún intento por resolver el problema, por lo cual técnicamente le estás haciendo los deberes. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
function clavesUnicas(obj1, obj2) {
let claves1 = Object.keys(obj1);
let claves2 = Object.keys(obj2);
resultado = [];

for(let i = 0; i < claves1.length; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < claves2.length; j++){
    }
    if(claves1[i] !== claves2[i]){
        resultado.push(claves1[i], claves2[i]);   
    }else {
        continue;
    }
}


return resultado;

};
```

Mi respuesta es más rudimentaria que las dos anteriores pero sirve. Primero pongo en dos arrays (clave1 y clave2), los keys de los objetos. Después itero con un bucle "for" anidado los dos arrays con las keys y meto las keys que son diferentes en otro array llamado resultado. Por último, devuelvo el array resultado.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero si detallas bien la pregunta, el OP no ha mostrado ningún intento por resolver el problema, por lo cual técnicamente le estás haciendo los deberes. Saludos

Comment: Tienes razón. Simplemente lo he visto como un reto para mi que también estoy aprendiendo pero no he caído en la cuenta que la persona que ha puesto la pregunta buscaba una respuesta rápida sin esforzarse lo más mínimo en intentar resolverla.